# How to declare a global variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I have an attribute in my class

```
class MITCampus(Campus):
    """ A MITCampus is a Campus that contains tents """
    def __init__(self, center_loc, tent_loc = Location(0,0)): 

        """ Assumes center_loc and tent_loc are Location objects 
        Initializes a new Campus centered at location center_loc 
        with a tent at location tent_loc """

        Campus.__init__(self,center_loc)



    def add_tent(self, new_tent_loc):
        """ Assumes new_tent_loc is a Location
        Adds new_tent_loc to the campus only if the tent is at least 0.5 distance 
        away from all other tents already there. Campus is unchanged otherwise.
        Returns True if it could add the tent, False otherwise. """
        # Your code here
```

In order to keep track of the locations I create a new variable know as tent_list = []. But the problem is that whenever a new instance of the MITCampus is created and the add_tent is called the tent_list is reset to empty list.

> Please help!!

Comment: Its not clear exactly what you are looking for here.  do you want to declare a class variable tent_list? in that case just do `tent_list=[]` above your init function for a class level variable.  However, if you want to make a global tent_list you could just declare tent_list above your class definition and refer to it using `global tent_list` inside your class.

Comment: I think you maybe confused about what is being asked of you. What information is inherited from `Campus`, I'm assuming this already maintains a list of tents.

Comment: I already answered one of your question and I think that you want to record all the tents created but not for each object. Am I right ?